# Allow access Android webview for camera in L class api 21

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I have simple webview for apprtc, but front camera is not running and not permission allow access camera. Build in eclipse ADT.

Sample code MainActivity onpermissionrequest :

```
mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        // Need to accept permissions to use the camera

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            L.d("onPermissionRequest");
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```

note : L error, I am not understand L function??
help for use sample code....

Logcat preview :
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Log.d("....");`

Answer (score 0):

L for Lollipop ...
and work for lolipop android sdk...